# Reading POST Data after auto-return

Tags: asp.net, paypal

On my .NET website I use both "Buy Now" and "Subscribe" buttons.

The "**buy now**" button works OK: after buying the visitor is returned to website and I see his Paypal details in POST (via Firebug), and I can access them with "Request.Form("...")

However, when I use "**Subscribe**" button, the user is returned to website with only empty GET request, as he was simply entering the URL.

- I use custom buttons. I tried also Paypal generated button - the same effect - no POST section.
- Both buttons are on the same page
- I use auto-redirect defined in Paypal
- IPN enabled (and works for "buy now").

How I can get the buyer's details when he does monthly subscription?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the return and rm parameters in your Subscribe button?  PayPal's docs state the following for the rm parameter, which sounds like what you need to adjust.

> Return method. The FORM METHOD used to send data to the URL specified
>   by the return variable. Allowable values are:
>
> - 0 – all shopping cart payments use the GET method
> - 1 – the buyer's
>     browser is redirected to the return URL by using the GET method, but
>     no payment variables are included
> - 2 – the buyer's browser is
>     redirected to the return URL by using the POST method, and all payment
>     variables are included The default is 0.
>
> Note: The rm variable takes effect only if the return variable is set.